# How to automatically show modal with 5 seconds delay with qTip plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip

How do I make the below modal pop-up automatically after 5 seconds? I'm not too familiar with jQuery or Javascript. I know it probably has something to do with window.onload but not quite sure how to implement it. Thanks.

```
 <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.tip').qtip({
        content: {
            text: $('#register'),
        },
        position: {
            my: 'center',
            at: 'center',
            target: $(document.body)
        },
        style: {
            classes: 'qtip-tipsy'
        },
        show: {
            modal: {
                on: true,
                blur: true, // Enables ability to exit when clicking on gray background
                escape: true // Enables exit by escape key
            },
            when: {

            }
        }
    })

    });

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="register">

    test

</div>

<button class="tip">Register</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

use [setTimeout()](http://www.google.com.pk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCwQFjAB&url=http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/settimeout-example/&ei=1c1cU4r4Ism_PPGogeAC&usg=AFQjCNED2ccclPLMGLwFR4Q-FzfiWyCnnQ&bvm=bv.65397613,d.ZWU)function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

       setTimeout(showPopup,5000); // call showPopup after 5 seconds

    });


function showPopup()
{

 $('.tip').qtip({
        content: {
            text: $('#register'),
        },
        position: {
            my: 'center',
            at: 'center',
            target: $(document.body)
        },
        style: {
            classes: 'qtip-tipsy'
        },
        show: {
            modal: {
                on: true,
                blur: true, // Enables ability to exit when clicking on gray background
                escape: true // Enables exit by escape key
            },
            when: {

            }
        }
    })

}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work yet... should the .tip part be changed? Because right now it's targeting to a button with class name "tip."

Comment: put alert is the function showPopup to see it is called or not?

Comment: also see firebug condole may be some syntax error coming